# Django admin input causes UnicodeDecodeError, how?

Tags: python, django, unicode, python-unicode

Today I received data via the Django admin which couldn't be encoded. Somehow the encoding of the data is not in unicode. How is this possible?

I have a `name` property at my `Client` model which returns the data in unicode:

```
@property
def name(self):
    return u'{0} {1}'.format(self.firstname, self.lastname).strip()
```

But this doesnt work:

```
>>> client
<Client: [Bad Unicode data]>

>>> client.lastname
'Dani\xc3\xabl'

>>> client.lastname.__class__
<type 'str'>

>>> u"{0} {1}".format(client.firstname, client.lastname)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Stange enough, encoding the first/lastname as regular string does work:

```
>>> "{0} {1}".format(client.firstname, client.lastname)
'Test Dani\xc3\xabl'

>>> "{0} {1}".format(client.firstname, client.lastname).decode('utf-8')
u'Test Dani\xebl'
```

What happened here? and how did this input get into my model via the admin?

System stack (it's an external server):

- Debian 6.0.5 (Squeeze)
- Django 1.4.1
- Python 2.6.6
- MySQL 5.1.49
- MySQL-python==1.2.2

This is the relevant model code:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(_("Firstname"), max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(_("Lastname"), max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email"), unique=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'clients'
        ordering = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0} <{1}>'.format(self.name, self.email)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return u'{0} {1}'.format(self.firstname, self.lastname).strip()
```

Comment: Just to be sure, I take it that `firstname` and `lastname` are fields? Could you post the relevant model code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to the collation you are using for your MySQL database.

Indeed, Django's behavior is to always return `unicode`strings when retrieving data form the database - which would work with your code, as there is nothing wrong with it.

However, as you can see in [the django documentation on database settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#collation-settings), section collation settings, using MySQLdb version 1.2.2 with an `utf8_bin`collated MySQL database will cause you to not to get unicode strings, but bytestrings, when retrieving charfields form the database.

You might want to investigate this issue (that is, check your MySQL collation settings), but it is likely that your problem is coming from there.

If this is the case, you will have to decode by hand any input that you are getting from MySQL. Alternatively, you could change the collation settings of your database.

You can use `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM %YOURDB%` to get the collation of the tables in your database.

---

#### Excerpt from the relevant documentation section:

> By default, with a UTF-8 database, MySQL will use the utf8_general_ci_swedish collation. This results in all string equality comparisons being done in a case-insensitive manner. That is, "Fred" and "freD" are considered equal at the database level. If you have a unique constraint on a field, it would be illegal to try to insert both "aa" and "AA" into the same column, since they compare as equal (and, hence, non-unique) with the default collation.
>
> In many cases, this default will not be a problem. However, if you really want case-sensitive comparisons on a particular column or table, you would change the column or table to use the utf8_bin collation. The main thing to be aware of in this case is that if you are using MySQLdb 1.2.2, the database backend in Django will then return bytestrings (instead of unicode strings) for any character fields it receive from the database. This is a strong variation from Django's normal practice of always returning unicode strings.

Comment: Autch... this seems to be the case. Any attempt to change the connection `OPTIONS` failed so far. The tables are indeed in `latin1_swedish_ci` collation. So far I haven't been able to fix the output of MySQLdb/Django however.

Comment: @vdboor You can always change the collation of a table / database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-table.html